# MYSQL: Split string with variable number of occurances

Tags: mysql, string, split

I have a column in a table which contains person's details in this format:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Team  |                                                                                                Members                                                                                                 |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Team 1 | OK-10:Jason:Jones:ID No:00000000:male:my notes                                                                                                                                                         |
| Team 2 | OK-10:Mike:James:ID No:00000001:male:my notes OZ-09:John:Rick:ID No:00000002:male:my notes                                                                                                             |
| Team 3 | OK-08:Michael:Knight:ID No:00000004:male:my notes2 OK-09:Helen:Rick:ID No:00000005:female:my notes3 OZ-10:Jane:James:ID No:00000034:female:my notes23 OK-09:Mary:Jane:ID No:00000023:female:my notes46 |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to split them in a new table like this:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| Team  | Member_Rank | Member_Name | Member_Surname | Member_ID_Method | Member_ID_Num | Member_Gender | Member_Notes |
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| Team1 | OK-10       | Jason       | Jones          | ID No            |      00000000 | male          | my notes     |
| Team2 | OK-10       | Mike        | James          | ID No            |      00000001 | male          | my notes     |
| Team2 | OZ-09       | John        | Rick           | ID No            |      00000002 | male          | my notes     |
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Splitting details:

Split Row Delimiter : ' O&-' where & can be only 'K' or 'Z'

Split Column Delimiter : ':'

One Team can contain many members, there is no upper limit

Is that possible?

Comment: You should read the existing data and handle the transformation in your program logic and not in SQL.

Comment: @juergend data is imported from CSV which I can't change its export procedure

Comment: If it is CSV from the start then read that into your program. Change it the way you like and afterwards save it in SQL

Comment: @juergend there is no program at all. I just have to import it to an existing database. Its a database migration project.

Comment: Then I would write a simple program to do that. There are plenty CSV readers out there and it is way easier to handle in java or C# than in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can handle this using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, but it is fairly ugly:

```
SELECT
    Team,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ':', 1) AS Member_Rank,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ':', 2), ':', -1) AS Member_Name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ':', 3), ':', -1) AS Member_Surname,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ':', 4), ':', -1) AS Member_ID_Method,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ':', 5), ':', -1) AS Member_ID_Num,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ':', 6), ':', -1) AS Member_Gender,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ':', -1) AS Member_Notes
FROM yourTable;
```

But I personally might reformat/split your data outside of MySQL, e.g. in an application language such as Java, and then reimport it as separate columns.

Comment: Thank you, but while it splits the strings, it doesn't create a new row if there are more than one member in a cell (using the ' O&:' delimiter)

Comment: I suggest not handling this within MySQL then.  Handle it in your application language.

Comment: well csv is not exported from an application I have access to... So I don't think that I can manipulate it before importing it

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job.  MySQL is not a text parsing tool (Perl is though).

Comment: I am using a batch file in order to import it in phpmyadmin, I don't know if its possible to edit the csv in order to split the rows using batch script....

Comment: You might want to open a new question asking how to do this using an application language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770257/split-string-with-variable-number-of-occurances-using-an-application-language